# Directed networks and weight on the edges with networkx

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have the following pandas dateframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_emp':[13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113],
    'name_emp': [
        'JL Consultores',
        'GRAAL OURINHOS',
        'SOJA COMERCIO DE DERIVADOS DE PETROLEO LTDA'
    ],
    'name_dep': [
        'DIONILSO MATEUS MARCON',
        'JOSE AUGUSTO ROSA',
        'LUCIO ANTONIO MOSQUINI'
    ],
    'donnated_value': [ 750.00, 5000.00, 27350.00],
    'donnated_amount': [1,1,1],
    'reimbursed_value':[36000.00,410.55, 241.22],
    'amount_reimbursed': [1,2,1],
    'roi':[4800.00, 8.21,0.88]
})
```

I need to create a directed network where df['name_dep'] and df['id_emp] are nodes.Then, each line of the dataframe provides two nodes, linked by an edge with weight. The weight of the edges is in agreement with the roi column: for values ​​of roi between 0 and 100, weight equal to 1; between 100 and 1000, weight equal to 2; Up to 1000, weight equal to 3. As the code below, I can plot a network for a specific name_dep:

```
G = nx.Graph()
deputado = 'DIONILSO MATEUS MARCON'
lista_subset_graph = list(df[df["name_dep"] == deputado]["id_emp"]) + 
[deputado]
H = G.subgraph(lista_subset_graph)
nx.draw(H, style = "solid", with_labels = True)
plt.savefig("teste.png")  
plt.show()
```

Now it is necessary to plot the network like all nodes and with weight on the edges. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Create graph
G = nx.Graph()
# Add id_emp nodes
G.add_nodes_from(df['id_emp'])
# Set 'name_emp' attribute for 'name_emp' column values
for node in G.nodes:
    G.nodes[node]['name_emp'] = df.loc[df['id_emp'] == node]['name_emp'].values[0]
# Add name_dep nodes
G.add_nodes_from(df['name_dep'])
# Create the new column with transformed 'roi' values
df['roi_new'] = df['roi'].apply(
    lambda x: 1 if x < 100 else 2 if 100 <= x < 1000 else 3
)
# Add weighted edges
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['id_emp', 'name_dep', 'roi_new']].values)
```

P.S. Looks like you should swap `name_dep` and `name_emp`, values in `name_emp` fit more for `name_dep`.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to differentiate the different types of nodes. How do I do that?

Comment: You can add `type_` attribute similar to loop with this comment: `# Set 'name_emp' attribute for 'name_emp' column values`